# Can't bind images to ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, binding

I know several questions have been asked on this topic but I've not found a solution in any of them.

The fields in 'FileImageInfo' model all bind ok except the image source.

I've followed several tutorials on this and I can't see what I'm doing differently..

```
//code behind
var items = new List<FileImageInfo>();            
       
    for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
    {                
       items.Add(new FileImageInfo
         {
            FileType = "Jpeg",
            FileSize = 3.4,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            imageSource = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1" 
//ImageSource.FromStream(() => images[i].AsPNG().AsStream())
         });                 
    }                     
    Items.ItemsSource = items;  


//model
public class FileImageInfo
    {            
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        public double FileSize { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        //public ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }
        public string imageSource;

        public FileImageInfo()
        {               
        }
    }

//Xaml

<StackLayout >
                <ListView BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="Items" HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>                            
                                <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Horizontal">                                        
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">                                                
                                            <Label Text="{Binding FileType}"></Label>
                                            <Label></Label>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding FileSize}"></Label>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding DateCreated}"></Label>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding imageSource}" />
                                    </StackLayout>                               
                                    <Label Text="Status" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>                          
                                </StackLayout>                            
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

I've narrowed the issue down to this section. If I hard code a value in the images array such as images[0] it works, but when I use the iterator variable images[i] nothing is displayed

```
for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new FileImageInfo
            {
                FileType = "Jpeg",
                FileSize = 3.4,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => 
images[i].AsPNG().AsStream())
        });                 
        }                     
        Items.ItemsSource = items;
```

Update - There is happening because there's something strange happening with the loop and I think it has something to do with the anonymous method

```
For example: if the for loop is: for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

then then you would expect the items list to only contain one item -
images[0]
but weirdly the item it contains is images[1].
It's like 'i' is getting incremented and THEN passed into images[] in the anonymous method

Comment: You don't have to use ImageSource for images at a url, Forms has an implicit converter setup that will work with a simple string. From what I can see, the issue in the code above is that imageSource is a field. You have to bind to properties. If you change it to a public string property and just return the url as a string, it should work.

Comment: @BenReierson thanks for you input. Even if I make ImageSource a property instead of a field it still doesn't work. I've also making the property a string and calling ToString on the assignment but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Froms shared code of `FileImageInfo` , modify type of `imageSource` from `string` to `ImageSource` as follow :

```
public class FileImageInfo
{
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public double FileSize { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }
    //public string imageSource { set; get; }

    public FileImageInfo()
    {
    }
}
```

Then adding `ItemSource` for **ListView** :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    items.Add(new FileImageInfo
    {
        FileType = "Jpeg",
        FileSize = 3.4,
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
        imageSource = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://s1.ax1x.com/2020/07/31/aQhvss.png"))
    }) ;
}
Items.ItemsSource = items;
```

Here I replace shared uri to mine , becasue shared uri is invalid in Image . And it will not show image as result . Suggest that using **https** uri .The error log as follow :

> ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid: Uri: http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1/

Now the image will show :

[image]

Note : If must need to use **http** uri , you can use [FFImageLoading Nuget Pagckage](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API) to show image .Then **FileImageInfo** class can use `sting` type for
`imageSource` .

```
public string imageSource { set; get; }
```

Then add data :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    items.Add(new FileImageInfo
    {
        FileType = "Jpeg",
        FileSize = 3.4,
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
        imageSource = "https://s1.ax1x.com/2020/07/31/aQhvss.png"
    }) ;
}
```

Used in Xaml :

```
xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"

<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                            Source="{Binding imageSource}"/>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I didn't realise a shared uri is invalid for lists. The uri I was using was just for testing. You will see this line commented out which is what I actually want to use - //ImageSource.FromStream(() => images[i].AsPNG().AsStream()). I tried setting to type of image source but didn't work

Comment: @Ryn9011 I don't know the data of `images[i]` in your project . Maybe the size of data is too large will mark the `ImageSource.FromStream` will not show image imediatelly or show unsuccessfully . You can have a try with `ImageSource.FromUri` to check whether it works .

Comment: thanks, but that's not what it was. I've narrowed the issue down further if you're able to take a look

Comment: @Ryn9011 Okey , got it, however can not reproduce it in my local site . Maybe you can share a sample project link here, I will check that.